# Google Maps API predefined marker icon with Coffeescript

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

Apologies for the rather simple question.... I'm fairly new to both coffeescript and Google Maps API.

I'm trying to replicate the circle symbol for a Marker in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined) example using coffeescript, but I'm struggling with the syntax on the `icon` statement.

Can anyone show me how to do write the following code in coffeescript, specifically the icon part?

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 10
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just drop the `var` and be done with it:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: map.getCenter(),
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 10
  }
})
```

Function-calling parentheses and object braces are often optional in CoffeeScript but you can still include them if it makes the code clearer to you.

Or you could drop the optional commas, parentheses, and braces:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker
  position: map.getCenter()
  icon:
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE
    scale: 10
```

Note that the parentheses on the `map.getCenter` call are **not** optional since that function is called without any arguments.

Or you could say:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker(
  position: map.getCenter()
  icon:
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE
    scale: 10
)
```

to make the nesting a little clearer. This is probably the one I'd use. If there was more nesting then I'd probably start adding braces to make the structure clearer or break it into pieces:

```
icon =
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE
  scale: 10
marker = new google.maps.Marker(
  position: map.getCenter()
  icon: icon
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed response - all makes sense now! Like you, I'd use the parentheses as there is quite a bit of nesting